# Criar dataframe pandas 1 chave e alguns valores não padronizado no dicionário

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Tenho um dicionário em Python:

`dict = {0:[['tela1'],['tela2'],['tela3']], 1:[['tela2']], 2:[['tela5'],['tela7']], 4:[['tela1'],['tela3']]}`

e gostaría de transformar em um dataframe da seguinte maneira:

| Id | Valores |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | tela1 |
| 0 | tela2 |
| 0 | tela3 |
| 1 | tela2 |
| 2 | tela5 |
| 2 | tela7 |
| 4 | tela1 |
| 4 | tela3 |

Comment: Coloque o que você tentou fazer na pergunta. Abraço!

Answer (score -2):

```
import pandas as pd

dicionario = {0:[['tela1'],['tela2'],['tela3']], 
              1:[['tela2']], 
              2:[['tela5'],['tela7']], 
              4:[['tela1'],['tela3']]}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dicionario, orient='index')
df = df.T.melt().dropna()
df = df.rename(columns={'variable':'id','value':'Valores'})
df = df.explode('Valores')
```

| id | Valores |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | tela1 |
| 0 | tela2 |
| 0 | tela3 |
| 1 | tela2 |
| 2 | tela5 |
| 2 | tela7 |
| 4 | tela1 |
| 4 | tela3 |

Uma das possíveis soluções utilizando from dict do pandas.

O melt serve para transformar colunas em linhas.
O explode serve para remover itens de dentro de uma lista e criar um novo registro.